# Pandas is it possible to have mask ignore all non-numerical values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

'm trying to mask values in a dataframe but I'm getting errors when I introduce strings into the dataframe.

My goal is to take any value that is less than 1 and turn it into a NaN. I have strings which I do not want turned into NaN's(since strings cannot be less than 1).

I simply use this command:

```py
df = df.mask(df.lt(1))
```

but I get this error -

```py
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Is there a way to not have to go through the pain of creating a new DF and then merging it back? Is there a way to ignore anything non-numeric?

Here is a example with data:

```
import pandas as pd 

# intialise data of lists. 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, 44, 1], 
                   "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2], 
                   "C":[20, 16, 7, 3, 8], 
                   "D":[14, 3, 17, 2, 6]}) 
df = df.mask(df.lt(19)) 
print(df)
# result
#       A     B     C   D
# 0   NaN   NaN  20.0 NaN
# 1   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
# 2   NaN  54.0   NaN NaN
# 3  44.0   NaN   NaN NaN
# 4   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Bob", "Mary", "John", "Paul", "Chris"], 
                   "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2], 
                   "C":[20, 16, 7, 3, 8], 
                   "D":[14, 3, 17, 2, 6]}) 
df1 = df1.mask(df1.lt(19)) 
print(df1)
```

error - `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we can filter by `dtypes` and change only those columns:

**Edited**

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Bob", "Mary", "John", "Paul", "Chris"], 
                   "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2], 
                   "C":[20, 16, 7, 3, 8], 
                   "D":[14, 3, 17, 2, 6]}) 
cols = df1.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns
df1[cols] = df1[cols].mask(df1[cols] < 19)
df1
```

As an alternate - `cols = df1.columns[[i for i,j in enumerate(df1.dtypes.tolist()) for x in [np.dtype('float64'),np.dtype('int64')] if j == x]]` also works!

Comment: Thanks, in my example, I also need floats, I tried this - data = data_name_frame
---> 34   cols = data.columns[data.dtypes == ['int64','float64']] and got the same error.

Comment: actually if I run it, it get the same error as well. cols = df1.columns[df1.dtypes == ['float64', 'int64']]